# What exactly does the AWS Pay For What You Use policy mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Well, I was fed up with the absurd host prices here in Brazil when I got to know AWS and the pay-as-you-go policy.

I recently started a course for the solution architect certification (SAA2), that's when I saw in the EC2 module that machines must be turned on/off/rebooted manually which worried me because I thought the way it charged was:
If there are users accessing the machine it will be running then you will be charged, otherwise the machines will not run and you will not be charged.

So is only the machine running on access counted or will there always be 730H of use? This worries me because AWS postgre hosting is expensive for us Brazilians, and maybe that kills our small business.

Comment: If the server is on, it's using resources, even if no one's accessing it. You pay for the hours it's turned on. RDS is quite expensive; you're paying quite a premium for AWS to manage it for you.

Comment: @ceejayoz I see, I suppose the same goes for serverless correct? Is there any solution to turn off the machine when you don't have access? For example, 30 minutes without access, it turns off and only turns on again when it has an access

Comment: Depends on the nature of the "serverless" solution. Some are set up via AWS Lambda that'd only charge per HTTP request processed - https://vapor.laravel.com/ works this way. It's not a viable solution for a database, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, when I said serveless I was referring to lambda, in the course I saw that there was an option of serveless in aurora, but aurora is already expensive by itself

Comment: Lambda is only paid for when you use it. It's not practical to turn a machine on when a web request comes in as it takes 30 seconds to 3 minutes for a server to boot, the request will time out. I agree AWS is expensive, it's really aimed at enterprises as it's cheaper than building a data center. If you want cheaper go with AWS Lightsail, Digital Ocean, or another provider. I have a AWE EC2 t3a.micro running five low volume Wordpress sites, MySQL, Nginx, and a few other things that costs me about US$6 a month from memory. I pay a few dollars more for S3 storage for backups.